# stack level too deep. Function<SystemStackError>

Tags: ruby

I have following method thats throwing the error in title. I know it happens if the method is recursive means if it invokes itslef. But my method is not being called by itself. Does anyone know why i am getting this error?

```
  def self.send_my_message
      sqs = Aws::SQS::Client.new(region: 'us-east-2')
      queue_name = "something"
      queue_url = sqs.get_queue_url(queue_name: queue_name).queue_url
      sqs.send_message(queue_url: queue_url, message_body: 'Hello world')
  end
```

Full stack trace errors:

```
    Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "stack level too deep",
  "errorType": "Function<SystemStackError>",
  "stackTrace": [
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `initialize_dup'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `dup'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `block in as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `map'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:134:in `as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `block in as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `map'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:134:in `as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `block in as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `map'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:134:in `as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `block in as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `map'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:134:in `as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `block in as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `map'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:134:in `as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `block in as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `map'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:134:in `as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `block in as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `map'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:134:in `as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `block in as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `map'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:134:in `as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `block in as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `map'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:134:in `as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `block in as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `map'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:134:in `as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `block in as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `map'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:134:in `as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `block in as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `map'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:134:in `as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `block in as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `map'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:134:in `as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `block in as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `map'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:134:in `as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `block in as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `map'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:134:in `as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `block in as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `map'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:134:in `as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `block in as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `map'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:134:in `as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `block in as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `map'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:134:in `as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `block in as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `map'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:134:in `as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `block in as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `map'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:134:in `as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `block in as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `map'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:134:in `as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `block in as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `map'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:134:in `as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `block in as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `map'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:134:in `as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `block in as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `map'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:134:in `as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `block in as_json'",
    "/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:152:in `map'"
  ]
}
```

Comment: whats your ruby and `aws-sdk-ruby` gem versions?

Comment: Can you give a full stack trace?

Comment: @MartinZinovsky I am testing this on aws so not sure about ruby version but i dont see i have aws-sdk-ruby gem in gemfile. Is that gem required?

Comment: @Glyoko added fullstacktrace. sorry couldnt format it well.

Comment: Try `message_body: {hello: :world}` and/or `message_body: {hello: :world}.to_json` please.

Comment: since everything except `queue_url` is a string, i suspect that it is not what you think. could you try a `queue_url.to_s` or `p` it somewhere to see if it's a complex object?

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin if i try `{hello: :world}` i get error `expected params[:message_body] to be a String, got value {:hello=>:world} (class: Hash) instead` and with .to_json i get stack level too deep.

Comment: @phoet i tried `.to_s` for queue_url..same error stack level too deep

Comment: if i comment out `sqs.send_message..` i dont get that error. it returns url. but i need to send message.